# Battlefield 3 crashes only when flying

Tags: pc, technical-issues, battlefield-3

My Battlefield 3 on PC only seems to crash (BF3.exe isnt responding, etc) when I am flying in a Jet during combat.  I have no idea why this is....

I currently have 6970 x 2 in Crossfire, stable OS: Windows 7 x64, 12GB RAM, i7 @ 3.8ghz with a 1200watt psu.

I have tried both the newest drivers for my video cards and the beta drivers: both do not fix this.  My battlefield is up to date and so is my OS.  I have tried reinstalling the game, to no avail.  I am able to watch my temperatures of my CPU, GPU, etc on my left monitor while playing and everything seems okay.

It only crashes when I am flying a jet: Majority of the time on Kharg Island.

Any ideas / input?

EDIT: I read on some other forums that DICE isn't too friendly with pre Overclocked video cards.  So I also tried down clocking ( QQ )  both of my cards and I still get random BF3 crashes.  Only in the jet.

Comment: Does it crash everytime you're flying or only sometimes? Does it freeze up the PC up totally or does BF itself just crash to desktop?

Comment: Only sometimes: Completely random from what I have noticed.  Only BF freezes, I have to alt+tab then Ctrl + Shift + Esc to quit BF ( only way to regain focus of desktop)

Comment: It would appear you are in good company - http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654347810707974/#!/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654347810707974/1/

Comment: Well I'm glad that I'm not alone, thank you for your backtracking.   Still hoping for any suggestions until some patch is released. :/

Comment: Perhaps I will give a bounty if I don't receive much input.. but I don't think it would even matter if it is a common issue.  But then again: That sparks the question: Why are some people experiencing this problem and others not?

Comment: you should also stop overclocking your CPU, or at least make 100% sure the bus speed isn't changed, see http://superuser.com/questions/343115/ati-crossfire-instability-and-horizontal-bands/343117#343117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically "how do I determine if my hardware is stable?"

Sounds like you've already tried

- making sure your video drivers are 100% up to date
- monitoring temperatures (though you should try the "open case with house fan blowing on it" to make absolutely sure)

But you have not tried

- removing ALL overclocks: CPU *and* GPU. Make everything run at absolute stock speeds to reduce variables.
- disable CrossFire in the drivers so you are only running on one video card, not two: does it still happen? (no need to physically remove the 2nd card, disabling CrossFire in the drivers should work)

The standard "is my system stable?" tests should be run:

- run [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) overnight and see if your CPU is stable
- run [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) overnight and see if your memory is stable
- run [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) for an hour or so (be careful as this thing loads GPUs far beyond any realistic load)

Warning: Battlefield 3 is known to be *extremely* GPU intensive and may cause more heat than most games.

Comment: I have been running benchmarks and other tests since this post and I haven't seen any complications or indication(s) of fault(s).  Thank you for your input, but I am not the only person with this issue as linked above from @Emerica

Comment: did you remove ALL overclocks? did you disable CrossFire? etc.

Comment: From all the testing I have done, it just seems to be a heat issue.  I had to remove the side panel of my tower, and crank up my fan speed manually through the CCC.  For some reason the CCC is off by 5 degrees and is not aggressive enough for automatic fan control.  Thanks for your input and testing.  I got these results from the one test I have never heard of: Furmark.